Springboot max per route seems to be not working in my use case
I have a spring boot micro service and when I perform performance testing I observed that the service is waiting to connect to backend. The connection time out I set for backend is 2 seconds but the service call seems to be taking 10 seconds. I tried increasing max per route thought I was exhausted of connections still it is the same behavior. Please let me know what would be the best solution to eliminate the delay in spring boot rest call to external service.
